# Load Multiple Arrays from Plist?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, load, nsarray, plist

I have seen plenty on how to fetch dictionaries and things from plists but how do I specify specifically which array I want to grab from my plist?

E.g. I have two arrays in a plist, one called `array1` and another called `array2` how do I end up with two NSArrays?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a .plist file your root object is either an array or a dictionary. If you say, you have 2 arrays in your plist, called `array1` and `array2`, that means your root object is a dictionary. So you load your plist into an `NSDictionary` and access your arrays like this:

```
NSDictionary *myPlistRoot = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSArray *array1 = [myPlistRoot objectForKey:@"array1"];
NSArray *array2 = [myPlistRoot objectForKey:@"array2"];
```

Answer (score 2):

The arrays will just be contained within the dictionary, so you get them out the same way you get any object out of a dictionary:

```
NSArray *array1 = [someDictionary objectForKey:@"array1"];
```